# CoreBluetooth data package lost when sending via withoutResponse

Tags: ios, swift, core-bluetooth

On iOS some data packets are lost via BLE.

On a characteristic we have the type `.withoutResponse` we check of course for `canSendWriteWithoutResponse` and `func peripheralIsReady(toSendWriteWithoutResponse peripheral: CBPeripheral)`.
This is also stated in the documentation.

> On the other hand, if you specify the write type as
> CBCharacteristicWriteType.withoutResponse, Core Bluetooth attempts to
> write the value but doesn't guarantee success. If the write doesn't
> succeed in this case, you aren't notified and you don't receive an
> error indicating the cause of the failure.

Anyone have an idea how I can fix this without switching to `withResponse` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BLE is a distributed protocol. It is *always* possible to lose data. The only way you can ensure that you haven't lost data is to receive some notification back that the data was received correctly (often called an ACK for Acknowledge). The standard BLE way to achieve this is with responses. But you're free to implement your own ACK scheme if you don't want to use the standard one.

As an example, you can create a "confirmation" characteristic in your peripheral that your central subscribes to. When you send a write, you would wait until you receive a notification from that characteristic. If you don't see a notification after some timeout, the write may have been lost. This re-implements the standard write-with-response system at a higher layer.

Several of the BLE protocols I work on are actually serial protocols (we write to a characteristic, and read responses from the same characteristic). We often implement the ACK directly into the serial protocol (for example, returning `<msgid>OK`) without needing a BLE write-response.

Another solution is to write to the characteristic, and then read from the characteristic to see if it's updated, provided the characteristic is symmetric in that way (many aren't). I am fairly certain that there's no write-caching that would bite you here, since BLE reads and writes often aren't symmetric, but you should double-check that before relying on it. (See the Core Bluetooth WWDC videos from 2019 and 2017.)

As with all distributed systems, it's also never possible to *know* that data was lost. It's possible that the data arrived, and that the response was lost. This is the nature of distributed protocols, and just has to be figured into the system. This is why it's possible to build a system that will deliver a message *at least* once (provided that delivery is ever possible), or a system that will deliver a message *at most* once, but it's impossible to build a system that will deliver a message *exactly* once.

If you have no control over your peripheral, and it doesn't provide any error detection mechanisms, then there's nothing you can do on the central (phone) side. You have to have some cooperation from both sides to build a fault-tolerant distributed protocol.

Comment: I don't think this answer answers the question. BLE is like TCP, so no reorderings or packet drops are possible. The only possible paket losses are the last ones before a connection times out. So if a receiver receives packet N + 1, it must also have received packet N. Now in the (G)ATT standard, a receiver may actually drop an incoming Write Without Response if buffers are full, but you don't do that, right? (at least no BLE stacks I've looked at do this). If you say you get dropped packets it seems like there is simply a bug in Apple's software that swallows packets before they are sent.

Comment: @Emil Everything above also applies equally to TCP. Both will do retransmissions at the transport layer, but not indefinitely, and absolutely can drop packets. You're correct that they will never be out of order, but losing a connection to a BLE device is common, and there can be packets in flight at that time. On iOS, write-without-response gets no error messages in this case. Even if you do receive a write failure error, you cannot know whether the packet was lost when being sent, or if it was delivered and processed, and the ACK was lost.

Comment: iOS explicitly does drop Write Without Response packets if there's memory pressure. (See WWDC 2017 What's New in Core Bluetooth.) This is the thing @BilalReffas is asking about. I know that the talk says "this is our promise to you," but I'm not quite certain how that can be absolutely true. Between the time you read the property and the time you send data, the memory situation could change. But it's possible they mean "it's very unlikely that things will change that fast." Apple is very bad about documenting these things explicitly. In any case, a write can *always* fail.

Comment: I suppose they mean "when the property is true, we have reserved some space for you in the outgoing packet buffer, and hence will not ignore your command as we would if the buffer was full".

Comment: Yeah, I guess there could be a single slot reserved for each existing CBPeripheral, and when you use your slot, you may not get another for awhile, but once you do, nothing can take it away. If they built it like that, it would match their docs.